# Pixelated low res OSM XYZ tiles on retina display

Tags: qgis, osx, xyz-tiles, retina

After installing the latest Qgis3 for Osx on my Macbookpro w Retina display the Qgis canvas is still pixelated and appears at a (seemingly) low resolution (when loading OSM XYZ tiles).  I knew this was an issue on previous versions of Qgis but I thought this was resolved in the latest version.  Is this just a settings adjustment issue?

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem you have but I think there are two problems here: yours looks like it is not in the CRS used for this (set project CRS to EPSG:3857 I believe) and secondly a problem that exists even when you do so, which is while the tiles no longer look "stretched" they are still sub-retina resolution. I haven't found solution to that latter problem yet.